# not using index in where clause

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause, clause

If i have the following in the where clause :

```
( approps_precio * moneda_valor BETWEEN 2000 AND 6000)
```

it does not use the idx_approps_precio index.

But

```
( approps_precio BETWEEN 2000 AND 6000)
```

does it very well.

Is there a way to add the * operation and still use the index?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered storing the product `approps_precio * moneda_valor` in a(n indexed) column of its own?  You could use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) to ensure its value remains consistent with the underlying columns.

Answer (score 1):

Is `moneda_valor` a constant? If not, an index on `approps_precio` is useless when you look for values of  approps_precio multiplied by moneda_valor.

Comment: is not a constant, is a value retrieved by a previous join.

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging around to find some *official* documentation to support what Paul DuBois (albeit a member of the MySQL documentation team) says in the fifth chapter "Query Optimization" of his book [MySQL (Developer's Library)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321833872):

> **Make indexed columns stand alone in comparison expressions.** If you use a column in a function call or as part of a more complex term in an arithmetic expression, MySQL can't use the index because it must compute the value of the expression for every row. Sometimes this is unavoidable, but many times you can rewrite a query to get the indexed column to appear by itself.

The best I can find is the section on [Optimizer Transpositions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-primary-optimizations.html#optimizer-transpositions) in the Internals manual:

> However, MySQL does not support transpositions where arithmetic exists. Thus:
>
> ```
> WHERE 5 = -column1
> ```
>
> is not treated the same as:
>
> ```
> WHERE column1 = -5
> ```
>
> Transpositions to expressions of the form column = constant are ideal for index lookups.

In this case, one can take advantage of the index on `approps_precio` by rewriting the filter criteria by dividing through by `moneda_valor`:

```
WHERE approps_precio BETWEEN 2000/moneda_valor AND 6000/moneda_valor
```

Note that MySQL will still need to evaluate the division for each record, so I'm not convinced that much will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The * operation makes your value 0 and hence outsite of the range when moneda_valor is null. So you can rewrite it as:

`approps_precio BETWEEN 2000 AND 6000 and moneda_valor IS NOT NULL`